# Bounding the time to multiply the first $n$ primes as $\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}\log\log{i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, products, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to bound the number of operations for computing the product of the first $n$ primes:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n p_i,\ \text{where}\ p_i\ \text{is the}\ i\text{th prime}$$

Since the $n$th prime [is close to](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Approximate_Value_of_Nth_Prime_Number) $n\log{n}$, its size in *bits* will be $\log{(n\log{n})}=\log{n}+\log{\log{n}}=O(\log{n})$ bits.

Given [recent advances](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document), let's assume that $k$-bit integers can be multiplied in $O(k\log{k})$ time.

Then, the time to multiply the first $n$ primes should be (roughly):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |p_i|\log{|p_i|} = \sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}\log{\log{i}}$$

The best I can do to bound this is $O(n\log^2{n})$ time as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}\log{\log{i}}
 &\le \sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}\log{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2{i} \le  \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2{n} = O(n\log^2{n})
\end{align*}

Yet, in some academic literature I'm reading, folks seem to be assuming this can be done in $O(n\log{n})$ time.

So, **my question is**: Is there a better bound on the above sum? (Or, did I mess up the analysis of the time?)

Comment: No, the sum is definitely not $O(n \log n)$. Consider only summing from $i \ge n/2$. Then the sum $\ge \log\log(n/2) \sum_{i \ge n/2} \log i$. Now $\sum_{i \ge n/2} \log i \sim  n/2\log(n)$ by considering the integral so the overall sum is at least $\Omega(n \log(n) \log \log n).$

Comment: I see, so $\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i} \log{\log{i}}\ge \sum_{i=n/2}^n \log{i} \log{\log{i}}\ge \log{\log{n/2}}\sum_{i=n/2}^n \log{i}$ and $\sum_{i=n/2}^n \log{i} \approx n\log{n}-n/2\log{n/2} \approx n/2 \log{n}$. Cool, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best upper-bound I can come up with is actually $O(n\log{n}\log{\log{n}})$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}\log{\log{i}}
   \le \log{\log{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i}  
   \le \log{\log{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n \log{n}
   = O(n\log{n}\log{\log{n}})
\end{align*}

Then, @SandeepSilwal showed a lower-bound of $\Omega(n\log{n}\log{\log{n}})$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \log{i} \log{\log{i}} &\ge \sum_{i=n/2}^n \log{i} \log{\log{i}}\ge \log{\log{n/2}}\sum_{i=n/2}^n \log{i} \\
 &\ge n/2 \log{n}\log{\log{n/2}}=\Omega(n\log{n}\log{\log{n}})
\end{align*}

Thus, it follows that multiplying the first $n$ primes takes $\Theta(n\log{n}\log{\log{n}})$ time.